# docker compose: No assignment of host names when bridge is used

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In order to make every container part of the default bridge, I added `network_mode: bridge` in every service. These became part of bridge but the containers are not getting attached with the hostnames. Below is the config.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    network_mode: bridge
    hostname: elasticsearch

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    network_mode: bridge
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    network_mode: bridge
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Docker compose up

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating docker-elk_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Creating docker-elk_kibana_1        ... done
Creating docker-elk_logstash_1      ... done
```

Docker network inspect

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f561a85fb2b22bbf251545c7021d57020cf152bd3a5c3c061c7d6b0cb4e267e5",
        "Created": "2018-09-19T07:02:49.36259364Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0aedc2ce900b8a51f028e58a85c8db9480fd2816874a608540a899a4daab32fd": {
                "Name": "docker-elk_kibana_1",
                "EndpointID": "df3af338e0accb880ccc44323e5581064ee8ef84574485f1928d12dc415b598e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3f2088847bd8e958a047093b1af879c91c4071f57f0105bb7bf80fb8df832d41": {
                "Name": "docker-elk_logstash_1",
                "EndpointID": "6588b7eece43144833ae2f9ffe753e3cc6c70d0891a587c3e9a4e9ca84993532",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ace35bb6fadd50823f64e9075b5972e6e3b24e8b73273a41e7a48f9eeff89da1": {
                "Name": "roach",
                "EndpointID": "dd058e3e9f46b2459f14a2e5bdf96eae277e81dcf7ac2e6ac1c97d8220ead30d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f90378063d2a0157110b77af39f2526347f1ea9634839e0d2c0c584fb14ff957": {
                "Name": "docker-elk_elasticsearch_1",
                "EndpointID": "294a2f67196788135f370bbf83526395ba4401afb25db9eb0b59fba7fd358912",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f954c218e5ab15c83c2a0e2c848549c18879613f6f46d07f7ebf71cc89b6e55b": {
                "Name": "rabbitmq",
                "EndpointID": "e675ddc6076fe2256553e8b367a82aa36f488457e06ae6cf969c2e04feeb9fb8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Docker inspect elasticsearch

```
$ docker inspect docker-elk_elasticsearch_1
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "31a438f8fcb3dd8efca37260e77d346f21239b36d8bb30f5f08db4b79880a5c9",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "9200/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9200"
                    }
                ],
                "9300/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9300"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/31a438f8fcb3",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "294a2f67196788135f370bbf83526395ba4401afb25db9eb0b59fba7fd358912",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "f561a85fb2b22bbf251545c7021d57020cf152bd3a5c3c061c7d6b0cb4e267e5",
                    "EndpointID": "294a2f67196788135f370bbf83526395ba4401afb25db9eb0b59fba7fd358912",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Kibana Logs where elastic search is inaccessible:

```
$ docker logs docker-elk_kibana_1

{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T05:27:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-20T05:27:05Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

However, everything works fine with below config where I haven't provided any network related config.

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/:/usr/share/kibana/config:ro
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Containers on the default bridge network cannot refer each other by host name, they can only refer each other by IP. You can find this in the docs here https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge.

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

The solution is to define your custom bridge network in the Compose file with `networks` as described here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks and add every container to this user defined network. On this network containers can resolve each other by name.